# Unable to start Jekyll server in --watch mode in Windows 7

Tags: jekyll

I'm trying to run Jekyll server in --watch mode in Windows 7. But it fails to start and throws an error message:

```
blog [ master ] > jekyll server --trace --watch
Configuration file: C:/vraa/repo/blog/_config.yml
            Source: C:/vraa/repo/blog
       Destination: C:/vraa/repo/blog/_site
      Generating...
                    done.
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-2.7.7/lib/listen/adapter/windows.rb:21:in `rescue in usable?': undefined method `_log' for Listen::Adapter::Windows:Class (NoMethodError)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-2.7.7/lib/listen/adapter/windows.rb:17:in `usable?'
```

While building the jekyll site and starting the server is successful, the `--watch` mode is the one that is failing.

Any ideas?

I'm using Jekyll version 2.0.03 in Windows 7 64 bit and my ruby version is 1.9.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been some changes in the newer versions of Jekyll (v 1.0+). The `--server` command is now obsolete. To run a server in watch mode, type the following:

```
jekyll serve --watch
```

Also, run the following to update your listen ruby gem to 2.7.8 (released on June 12, 2014) which has your bug fixed:

```
gem update listen
```

That should get you running.

Answer (score 2):

update your 'listen' gem to 2.7.8

Answer (score 1):

Figured out what was the problem. It was the 'listen' ruby gem version that was causing the jekyll to start in `--watch` mode. Reverted the 'listen' gem to an old version then the server starts fine (though, with a warning but not a showstopper).

```
gem uninstall listen --version 2.7.7
gem install listen --version 2.6.0
```